# Connection issues on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: connection, ethernet

So I have this tp link adapter (TL-PA4010) and Ubuntu finds and connects to the Ethernet but it's so slow... It feels worst then the dial-up connections back in the days.

Do you have any idea on how to solve it?? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You state that it 'feels' slow; have you done any real testing already? Try downloading a file and report the speed. Do a [speedtest](http://www.speedtest.net) and report the ping etc. When is it slow, only the internet, or also on your own network when, for example, copying files between computers? We need more information before we can help you.

Comment: It's 25kb\s down and 1150kb\s up. - speedtest.net.
it should be around 50mb\s down and 3mb\s up.

Comment: I agree that this speed will feel slow :-)  
The 50Mbit / 3 Mbit values you specify are the default specifications of a VDSL line. Depending on the distance of the DSLAM (telephone'box' on the street to where your copper pair goes to) this speed will be this max, or less.  
The upload speed is 1150Kbit, this is 143KB/s. this is good for your line. I guess your download should be around 19Mbit, what equals to 2.4MB/s.  
The question is: Is this caused by the TL-PA4010 EoP adapter or by the Internet connection itself. Do other computers on the same network have the same issue?